# Cannot create object in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, officewriter

I have softartisans office writer version 8 and also installed excel viewer.I want to open excel by my application which is developed in classic asp and vb.So when i run application it says

"cant create object"

```
Server.CreateObject(SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.ExcelWriter)
```

Answer (score 3):

That error message can appear when the object you are trying to use is not registered on your server. Usually there is a DLL file that gets registered as part of the software installation or you have to manually register the DLL file using cmd.exe and regsvr32.exe.

[Version 8](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/ExcelWriter+Overview) of OfficeWriter that you reference appears to be a .Net application and therefore unlikely to be compatible with ASP Classic. [Version 3.9.2](http://docs.softartisans.com/OfficeWriterWindows/3.9.2/ExcelWriterASP/quickstart/first.aspx) was an ASP Classic version if you can still find a copy of that.

Alternatively you may be trying to create an object that doesn't exist because your call is wrong, e.g. should it instead be something else (check the manual) like the below example.

```
Server.CreateObject("Softartisans.ExcelWriter")
```

Comment: To add: Starting in OfficeWriter 4.6.0, the classic ASP components are no longer distributed with the installer. There are 4.6.0 and 4.6.1 builds available if you contact the support team (www.officewriter.com/support). Note: I work for SoftArtisans, makers of OfficeWriter.

Comment: ya I understand,after checking all things i found that i need to install version 4,but cannot find link

Comment: As @AlisonB commented you can contact the Softartisans support team at www.officewriter.com/support